# 80's 90'sTV series/movie identification, live-action: bad guy turns to be the good one

Tags: story-identification, planets

I remember a sci-fi show/movie as a child where a kid/teen and a generic hero traveled to other planets. One was a mushroom people one, another was a giant people one, can't remember more. They were always followed by a dark red robot/suit. This enemy at some point was revealed to be the real good guy, just when he removed his helm. I think he was a black guy. The whole time, he had been trying to save the kid from the other guy. Then, he helped the kid and fight the false hero. Can't remember more.

If someone know something about this please tell me.

Comment: We dont know when you were a child.... Give us an Idea how long ago this was or a decade... (ie 70s)

Comment: Saw it at 90's, may be same decade or 80's.

Answer (score 5):

[*Josh Kirby... Time Warrior!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Kirby..._Time_Warrior!) a 6 movie series.

> The series concerns a device, found by humans in the 25th century, called the Nullifier. This device is said to be capable of destroying the universe. Realizing the danger, a man called Irwin 1138 splits the Nullifier into six pieces, which are then dispersed through time. However, a scientist called Dr. Zoetrope finds out where the pieces are located and, with the help of his time traveling armor, sets about reassembling the device. Along with 20th century teenager Josh Kirby, and a half-human warrior known as Azabeth Siege, Irwin 1138 sets about thwarting Dr. Zoetrope's plans.

Comment: ^_^ Congrats on the self-answer! Don't forget to accept in about 42 hours by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. Clicking early will tell you how much time you have left.

Comment: Also, this one has come up several times before, so we will be closing this as a Duplicate. You still get credit for the question, and answer, and you can (and should) still accept it. This is just a method of bookkeeping to make the questions linked.

Comment: Incidentally, we get this one a lot, so you're in good company. :)