# Sci fi TV series about a parallel universe where belts let them stay there and give them power

Tags: story-identification, tv, parallel-universe

I'm looking for a TV show that I watched when I was a kid (2000s). It's not *Sliders*, *Parallax*, *Spellbinder*, or *Stormworld*.

It's about a boy who travels in a group with a girl and an old man (maybe a doctor or scientist), looking for some crystals-ish to fix a machine. They travel with a companion, who is a puppet. They use belts that if they take it out they leave that parallel universe.

In the end, the villain turns out to be the good guy, and the scientist who they are traveling with, the bad. They all take their belts to give power to the protagonist's, and defeat the scientist.

Comment: 'They use belts that if they take it out they leave that parallel universe.'
If they take something out of the belt (if so, what?), or if they take the belt off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the TV or movies series you remember, when the main characters, including a boy and a girl, have a quest and travel in time and/or space, possibly to parallel worlds, and at the end there is a switch in who the good side and the bad side are reversed, is probably [*Josh Kirby: Time Warrior!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Kirby..._Time_Warrior!) (1995,1996).  I have only seen part of the series as far as I remember, but there have been a number of questions about it.

[Obscure kids (non animated) movie/film series from the 90's or so](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71927/obscure-kids-non-animated-movie-film-series-from-the-90s-or-so/79685#79685)

[90s (or early 2000s) scifi (mini)series where a boy and old man chase a black guy in metal suit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56401/90s-or-early-2000s-scifi-miniseries-where-a-boy-and-old-man-chase-a-black-gu/56405#56405)

[80's 90'sTV series/movie identification, live-action: bad guy turns to be the good one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217295/80s-90stv-series-movie-identification-live-action-bad-guy-turns-to-be-the-go/217297#217297)

Comment: that's the one. Thank you very much.
Years looking for that.